# Why does my duration = calendar days for a 5 day work week?

Tags: ms-project

[image]

shouldn't the calendar days be 2/7th longer than the duration if we're not working Saturdays and Sundays?

Comment: What do you want to do?

Comment: I am trying to calculate the correct end date for the project. However I am skeptical of this answer because my duration days = calendar days when the schedule is set to a 5 day work week.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is correct. There are 62 weeks between 1/14/2004 and 3/22/2005.

Let's say you have a task that starts on Monday, June 10, 2019 and finishes on Friday, June 21, 2019. That is 10 work days which is the same as 2 work weeks. The duration could be entered as `2 wks`, `10 days`, `80 hrs`—all are equivalent and correct.

**Update for additional question**

Use the [DateDiff](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/datediff-function) function in a calculated field to show the elapsed (calendar) time between two dates. Customize a number field, e.g. `Number1`, with this formula: `DateDiff("h",[Start],[Finish])` to show the elapsed hours between the start and finish of each task. In the example above, the answer would be 273 hours between 6/10/2019 8:00 AM and 6/21/2019 5:00 PM.

Since some task durations might not be shown in hours, use this formula in another number field to calculate the duration in hours for comparison: `ProjDateDiff([Start],[Finish])/60`. (For information on this function see the vba reference, where it's called [DateDifference](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.application.datedifference).)

For tips on how to use custom fields: [Microsoft Project Custom Formula Guide](https://www.mpug.com/webnlearn-recordings/microsoft-project-custom-formula-guide/), [Working with Custom Fields and Formulas in Microsoft Project](https://www.lynda.com/Project-tutorials/Working-Custom-Fields-Formulas-Microsoft-Project/555800-2.html)

Comment: Oooo. Thank you, i think this just clicked. Is there a way to compare actual work to calendar work in project to gauge spare time? I.e. If I have a 40 hour task (1 week), I want to be able to compare it to the 168 potential hours in a week (24x7).